# How to assign each row of an arraylist to its own array

Tags: java

I am able to convert my csv file into an arraylist, but I want to be able to find the mean and standard deviation of each row in my arraylist. I would like to do this by converting each row to an individual array to be able to call for future use.

```
    BufferedReader gradeBuffer = null;

    try {
        String gradeLine;
        gradeBuffer = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("Assignment4-datafile.csv"));

        // Read in file line by line
        while ((gradeLine = gradeBuffer.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(gradeCSVtoArrayList(gradeLine));
        }
        //throw exception if file not found
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            if (gradeBuffer != null) gradeBuffer.close();
        } catch (IOException gradeException) {
            gradeException.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

// Convert CSV to ArrayList using Split
public static ArrayList<String> gradeCSVtoArrayList(String gradeCSV) {
    ArrayList<String> gradeResult = new ArrayList<String>();

    if (gradeCSV != null) {
        String[] splitData = gradeCSV.split("\\s*,\\s*");
        for (int i = 0; i < splitData.length; i++) {
            if (!(splitData[i] == null) || !(splitData[i].length() == 0)) {
                gradeResult.add(splitData[i].trim());

            }
        }
    }

    return gradeResult;

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I think the first thing that you need to do is change `gradeCSVtoArrayList` to return a List of numbers, either Long or Double depending on if it is integer or floating point numbers.

```
public static ArrayList<Long> gradeCSVtoArrayList(String gradeCSV) {
    ArrayList<Long> gradeResult = new ArrayList<Long>();

    if (gradeCSV != null) {
        String[] splitData = gradeCSV.split("\\s*,\\s*");
        for (int i = 0; i < splitData.length; i++) {
            if (!(splitData[i] == null) || !(splitData[i].length() == 0)) {
                gradeResult.add(Long.parseLong(splitData[i].trim()));

            }
        }
    }

    return gradeResult;
}
```

WIth this list you can find mean and standard deviation.

Comment: That is super helpful!  However, in the CSV files that are being uploaded, the first row of data are string values, and the rest of the rows are the ones that I would like to manipulate.  Is there a way to skip over the first row of data when returning my list?

Comment: If you are sure that there will always be a line and you need to omit it, just add a `gradeBuffer.readLine()` before you start the while loop.